# Repeated calls to Calendar.Events.list from Google Apps script yield different results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Every time that I run the following code from a Google App Script attached to a Google form I keep getting different results:

```
  var calendarId = 'a_valid_calendar_ID';
  var eventTime = '2019-03-05T07:00:00.000Z';
  var results = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {'singleEvents': true, 'timeMin': eventTime, 'maxResults': 1});
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4))
```

On each running of the script the returned calendar event is the next calendar event after the event that was returned on the previous running of the script!  Is there some way to reset the session so that `results` will always reference the first calendar event on or after the `eventTime`?

Comment: When tested, this piece of code always returns the same entry, even when run multiple times in a row, or many `Calendar.Events.list()` calls in a row. I assume this is a minimal example, so the problem must exist somewhere in your actual code. You'll have to edit your post and share that for me to help!

Comment: I get the same results as @Chris.  Always the same result.

Comment: Note that there is actually an event starting at `eventTime`, and these events repeat every night, and during the day on weekends and public holidays.  I created a new script file in the project with just that code. Here is the truncated output of running it twice (note that the first time that I ran this, the returned event is already well into the future):

Comment: [19-02-26 07:17:04:166 AEDT] {
    "description": ...,
    "accessRole": "owner",...,
    "updated": "2019-02-25T10:51:45.973Z",
    "items": [
        {
           ... "kind": "calendar#event",
            ..."end": {
                "dateTime": "2019-03-11T06:00:00+11:00",
                "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney"
            },
            ..."start": {
                "dateTime": "2019-03-10T18:00:00+11:00",
                "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney"
            },
            ...}

Comment: [19-02-25 12:28:37:947 PST] {
   ... "accessRole": "owner",
   ... "kind": "calendar#events",
    "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
   ... "updated": "2019-02-25T10:51:45.973Z",
    "items": [
   ...         "kind": "calendar#event",
...      "end": {
                "dateTime": "2019-03-11T06:00:00+11:00",
                "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney"
            },
   ...         "start": {
                "dateTime": "2019-03-10T18:00:00+11:00",
                "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney"
            },
...}

Comment: At least it stopped ratcheting forward in time, but it is still skipping over many events.

Comment: When I try this on a different calendar where I created a 12 hour overnight event starting at `eventTime` as well as two others over the next 2 days, the event that is returned is an all-day event from March 11, 2019 (Australia/Sydney time) that I had imported into the calendar a week ago.  Is this some sort of a timezone bug?  (NB this is not the only weirdness that I am experiencing, as Google Forms still don't update linked Google Sheets correctly for me, despite being informed by support that the problem has been fixed)

Comment: Can you get someone to run this in Australia's Google servers?

Comment: Just to clarify my first comment: all events are individual events, and are not part of a recurring series.

Comment: Same results with a completely new project, same code and the same calendars... returning the same results as above.

Comment: `Calendar.Events.list()` can return multiple events, but you are restricting it to just one with `'maxResults': 1`. It's possible the same events are trying to be returned but are filtered to 1 every time. Try to allow a few more results through and see if they are consistent. `'maxResults': 5`. I'd also want to confirm the simple mistakes and make sure these events are on the same calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `orderBy` option, otherwise what is returned is the event that has a **start time** on or after `timeMin`, but was the **oldest to have been edited**.  The code therefore should be:

```
  var calendarId = 'a_valid_calendar_ID';
  var eventTime = '2019-03-05T07:00:00.000Z';
  var optionalArgs = {'singleEvents': true, 'timeMin': eventTime, 'maxResults': 1, 'orderBy': 'startTime'};
  var results = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4))
```

I figured this out when I noticed that the returned JSON had a `nextPageToken` field despite the fact that I only wanted one result - `'maxResults': 1`

The reason that I was getting different results every time I ran my own code was that I would use the `id` of the event to modify that event.  If I then ran the same code with exactly the same arguments, the edited event was no longer the oldest to have been edited with a startTime after `timeMin`, and therefore I was being given the next event after that one!

The behaviour of this API is somewhat counterintuitive and could be improved by:

1. make the default behaviour to be using the optional arguments `{'singleEvents': true, 'orderBy': 'startTime'}`
2. change the name of the `maxResults` option to `maxResultsPerPage` to make it explicit as to what the `max` refers to

In the meantime the docs should be edited to draw attention to this somewhat unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Nice, looks like I was on the right track with my comment - just a little late. Though I think the behaviour is clear in this case

Comment: Chris, I don't think that an API should be a straightforward dump of a SQL query against the database, but rather should present the information in a meaningful way.  What do you think about my suggestions for improvement?  Perhaps something for v4? ;) Cheers!

Comment: I dunno, I'm definitely not an expert, but it seems your suggestions might make sense for your use-case (chronological), but the uses for this API can vary widely. The [Pagination](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/pagination) section explains what they do pretty well. In my testing using your minimal example, the results were very consistent, serving results in order of creation/edition. Honestly, I think it would be fine either way, as long as the user understands how the data is being served (which the API docs do explain somewhat poorly in the parameter descriptions).